# Load text in Punjabi language in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, text, multilingual

I have received response from back-end in the below mentioned form, I want to display content in Punjabi, Gurmukhi Punjabi and English language simultaneously,

```
  {
            "AK_Index" = "APNE SEVAK KEE AAPE RAKE";
            Ang = 747;
            Author = "Guru Arjan Dev Ji";
            Bani = "<null>";
            "Bani_ID" = "<null>";
            English = "Guru Nanak has met the Supreme Lord God; I am a sacrifice to Your Feet. ||4||1||47||";
            "English_Initials" = gnmptckb;
            Gurmukhi = "guru nwnku imilAw pwrbRhmu qyirAw crxw kau bilhwrw ]4]1]47]";
            "Gurmukhi_Initials" = "gnmpqckb]";
            ID = 32133;
            Kirtan = Kirtan;
            "Kirtan_ID" = 2853;
            Punjabi = "gurU nwnk Awpxy prm pRBU nUM iml ipAw hY Aqy aus dy pYrW qoN GolI jWdw hY[";
            Raag = "Raag Soohee";
            "Teeka_Arth" = "hy pRBU! mYN qyry crnW qoN sdky jWdw hW[ ijs mnu`K nUM gurU nwnk iml ipAw, aus nUM prmwqmw iml ipAw ]4]1]47]";
            "Teeka_Pad_Arth" = "kau = nUM, qoN ]4]1]47]";
        }
```

Attached is screenshot what the result would look like. The screenshot is from android. I want exact same result in iOS.

[image]
How to achieve this in iOS.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: SSA veer ji: Please look at https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014 and https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/. These might be helpful

Comment: Working with NSAttributedString might be helpful...

Comment: @AmarjitSingh SSA veer, but localisation won't work in this case, as content is dynamic and is coming from back end, for which I have to do conversion at my end while displaying.

Comment: @AhmadF But how to achieve conversion form english text to punjabi language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working using "Gurblipi.ttf" font which internally changes the English text to Punjabi language.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

for shabadDetail in shabadDetailList {
    attributedString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: shabadDetail.gurmukhi, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : FontHelper.guruLippi(fontsize: textview.font!.pointSize), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: TextFormatting.gurbaniColor]))
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: TextFormatting.doubleLineBreak))
}

textview.attributedText = attributedString
textview.textAlignment = .center
```

No encoding is required from native or back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension to change color font of some particular string.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

func setFontColorAndSize(_ textToFind : String,withColor color: UIColor,andFont font :UIFont){
    let range = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
    if range.location != NSNotFound {
        setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : font,NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor :color], range: range)
    }
}

// This is how you change 
let resultString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello") // convert any string to mutable attributed 
resultString.setFontColorAndSize("hel", withColor: UIColor.grey, andFont: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)) // pass the string you want to set particular color and font 
UILabel.attributedText = resultString // than update the label
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much you can do on the mobile end. You can ask server to send UTF-8 encoded data instead of plain English string.

```
English = UTF-8 encoded English string data//data for hello
Gurmukhi =  UTF-8 encoded Punjabi string data //data for ਪਜੌਬਹਗਕਤਚਜ
```

Now you can create the string to display in that language as:-

```
 let englishString = String(data: English, encoding: .utf8)
 let punjabiSring = String(data: Gurmukhi, encoding: .utf8)
```

Initializer is

```
init?(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)
```

Comment: Its working in android with this data only, so I was thinking there must be some alternate to make it work in iOS as well, rather than doing encoding from server end.